# Python data missing at random in two different arrays. Looking to combine these to make a single array

Tags: python, r, random, numpy, nan

I've recently started using Python (and have also started looking at R).I came across an interesting example (copied below for reference) in R which I wanted to try and see if I could implement in Python (without using rpy or Pandas etc.).

R code-example

```
# Goal:
#       A stock is traded on 2 exchanges.
#       Price data is missing at random on both exchanges owing to non-trading.
#       We want to make a single price time-series utilising information
#       from both exchanges. I.e., missing data for exchange 1 will
#       be replaced by information for exchange 2 (if observed).
# Let's create some example data for the problem.
e1 <- runif(15)                         # Prices on exchange 1
e2 <- e1 + 0.05*rnorm(15)               # Prices on exchange 2.
cbind(e1, e2)
# Blow away 5 points from each at random.
e1[sample(1:15, 5)] <- NA
e2[sample(1:15, 5)] <- NA
cbind(e1, e2)
# Now how do we reconstruct a time-series that tries to utilise both?
combined <- e1                          # Do use the more liquid exchange here.
missing <- is.na(combined)
combined[missing] <- e2[missing]        # if it's also missing, I don't care.
cbind(e1, e2, combined)
```

I have tried

```
import numpy as np 
e1=np.random.random((15,)).reshape(-1,1)
e2=e1+0.05*np.random.standard_normal(15).reshape(-1,1)
np.concatenate((e1,e2),axis=1) # cbind equivalent on two vectors
```

I have not managed to do the next section i.e.

```
# Blow away 5 points from each at random
```

I did try python's `np.random.random_sample` command but could not get it to work at all.
I would very much appreciate your assistance please with this and the last section i.e. reconstructing the timeseries that tries to utilise both data arrays as described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "random" package

```
import numpy as np 
import random
e1=np.random.random((15,)).reshape(-1,1)
e2=e1+0.05*np.random.standard_normal(15).reshape(-1,1)
e1[random.sample(range(e1.shape[0]), 5),:] = np.nan
e2[random.sample(range(e2.shape[0]), 5),:] = np.nan
np.concatenate((e1,e2),axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you (Kith) for your reply. I was able to finish the rest of the translation from R to Python code. Using the np.isnan(e1) function was easy to use. Big thumbs up for Python!